# NGINX proxy_pass returning 405 on POST request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect

I'm trying to set up nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect POST requests from `http://example.com:5318/msh` to `http://localhost:5000/msh`. This is my config:

```
http { 
  server {
    listen        5318;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    location /msh {
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000/msh;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;

      proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }   
  }
}
```

However when I send a POST request through, I get `405 Not Allowed` back from NGINX. The access.log logs that a 301 was returned, and nothing else. The endpoint `/msh` is not static content.